# MySQL Like function only works on some tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I have two tables within the same database.

On one I can use the MySQL function `LIKE` to locate a company name.  On the other I always get returned zero results, even when I use a simple match like:

```
SELECT name 
  FROM table 
 WHERE name LIKE 'a%'
```

Is there a reason for this?  Is there a setting or something that needs to be changed?

Comment: @XSaint32 -  MyIsam, also the collation is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try seeing if you get anything by simply using

```
SELECT name FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%'
```

Maybe nothing starts with a?

Comment: Just using '%' worked and lead me to the answer.  There is whitespace in front of the names, which is another issue, and therefore I need a % in front of everything.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please provide an example of the table population and MySQL output. Perhaps you really don't have any names that start with 'a'.

Comment: Agreed.  Could also be the collation is case sensitive, so there's nothing with 'a' because they all start with 'A'.  Just have to ask oneself - if I'm not getting any data, is there any that actually matches my criteria to begin with?

Comment: No I'm in PHPMyAdmin looking at the tables, and I definitely have names in there that start with 'a', also I have tried both 'A' and 'a' and neither work.